# Merge Laravel unique validations with array generic validations

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I found a code snippet that solved the problem I had with uniqueness validation, when dealing with arrays:

```
$rules = [  // this ones are ok for all
    'staff.*.name' => 'required|max:128',
    'staff.*.description' => 'max:512',
    'staff.*.anothervalue' => 'string',
];
// here loop through the staff array to add the ignore
foreach($request->staff as $key => $staff) {
    if ( array_key_exists('id', $staff) && $staff['id'] ) { // if have an id, means an update, so add the id to ignore
        $rules = array_merge($rules, ['staff.'.$key.'.email' => 'required|email|unique:users,id,'.$staff['id']]);
    } else {  // just check if the email it's not unique
        $rules = array_merge($rules, ['staff.'.$key.'.email' => 'required|email|unique:users']);
    }
}
```

Now I need to go a step further and avoid duplication of email values inside the same array (not in database), so I found the "distinct" rule in Laravel documentation. Also, there is the need for making the email values required only if some another value is present in the same array entry. I see that there is a "required_with" rule that comes handy in those situations. However, I can't find the way to combine the rules generated with the foreach loop with those that use the "wildcard" array notation.

Your suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: You issue is that you are mixing `update` and `create`, that is really bad as it generates a lot of issues like this one. Always use 2 different controller's method, NEVER mix `update` and `create`. If you understand SOLID, you are using 1 method for 2 different reasons, that is the S "Single responsibility". Also CRUD always is `index`, `show`, `edit`, `update`, `create`, `store` and `delete`, but never a mix of `update` and `create`, so try to stick to the standards and if you can't, explain a little more about the usage of this and where it is being used (controller).

Answer (score 0):

~~You can mix and match.~~

Edit: Turns out you cannot.

So you would need to overwrite the rule each time, or set all the rules as per `staff.*.email` when keyed individually; or make some custom validation logic that throws a `BadRequestHttpException`/`ValidationException` or similar.

e.g.:

```
foreach ...
    $rules['staff.'.$key.'.email' => 'required_with:staff.*.id|email|distinct|unique:users']);
```

Comment: I tried that, but It doesn't work. I think only the last rule set in $rules array for a particular value element under validation is applied. Are you sure rules can be mixed in that way?

Comment: Oh damn. Another test and you are right... the second one does indeed overwrite the first. Odd!